# Mapped type using `keyof` does not give a type error for missing properties

Tags: typescript

```
type Test = {
  a?: string;
  b?: string;
};

const test1: {
  [K in keyof Test]: K;
} = {};

type Keys = keyof Test;

// This causes a TS error `TS2739: Type {} is missing the following properties from type { a: "a"; b: "b"; }: a, b`
const test2: {
  [K in Keys]: K;
} = {};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQUoEMD8AXFIgE4CWAdgOYDcWUARoccOdXQL50YDGA9hURRgCYAEYimbAG0A0lEpQA1hBB8AZrFEBdIrM4p0XDBlCQos1fEMq1muIjr9BSEYgBMk+nIUULV3QsDVDQOE2chN2AAZiIAJQh+EgATAB5LEHgAGhY2KgA+EOMI11EAFnjEvhTU2w0tRBzSSgKimiA)

When creating a mapped type, TypeScript does not give a type error for missing properties when using the `keyof` operator. However, if I extract the `keyof Test` to its own type and use it in the mapped type, I get a type error as expected.

I also see that when using `Record`, I get a type error with the custom type and with `keyof`:

```
const test3: Record<Keys, string> = {};
const test4: Record<keyof Test, string> = {};
```

Why is that?

Comment: It has to do with whether or not the mapped type is "homomorphic" although this term isn't part of the new handbook documentation. See the other q/a for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found an explanation for this, but my understanding is when constructing a mapped type `test1` from another type with optional keys, the "optionality" will be inherited, whereas when getting the keys in `Keys` using `keyof Test` the "optionality" is ignored.

In `test2` you define a mapped type using now "required" keys from `Keys` with an empty object as a value, so typescript, as expected, throws an error.

---

**Edit1:** you can also remove the "optionality" while constructing a mapped type using this syntax, as described in typescript [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers):

```
const test1: {
  [K in keyof Test]-?: K;
} = {};
```